# T-SQL Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '12-02' to data type int

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to convert this NVARCHAR value into a periodeId.
The Raw data could be '12-02'.

My solution for this was first to try this

```
(1000+CONVERT(INT,LEFT(2,T1.PERIOD_NAME)))*100+CONVERT(Int,RIGHT(2,t1.PERIOD_NAME))
```

But i get the same error message here and could find any quick solution for it.

I also tried to just do a simple

`LEFT(2,T1.PERIOD_NAME)` to see if it was the formula itself that crashed it, but the same error came up.

Comment: What would be the integer equivalent of `'12-02'`?

Comment: Perhaps the error is elsewhere - why not edit your question to include the whole query?

Comment: You have data in your table like '12-2'...

Comment: Really LEFT(2,T1.PERIOD_NAME) had the same error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `'12-02'` to be 1202, then use `replace()` to remove the hyphen before conversion:

```
select cast(replace(period_name, '-', '') as int)
```

In SQL Server 2012+, you should use `try_convert()`, in case there are other unexpected values.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
SELECT (1000+CONVERT(INT,LEFT(t1.PERIOD_NAME,2)))*100+CONVERT(Int,RIGHT(t1.PERIOD_NAME,2))
```

The *character_expression* that [**LEFT**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) operates on is at first place, whereas the integer expression that specifies how many characters of the *character_expression* will be returned, comes at second place.